# I need to slice 20191231 as 2019 and 12 and 31 separately from a Panda DataFrame Series

Tags: python-3.x

`mdate` was originally numeric in the file with value: `20191231`

I am trying to split and get that into `2019`, `12` and `31`

`df['mdate']=df['mdate'].astype(str) df['yyyy'=df['mdate'].str.slice(0,4)
df['mm']=df['mdate'].str.slice(5,2) df['dd']=df['mdate'].str.slice(7,2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

1. Cast the column to `string` using [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html).
2. Convert the string column to date using [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and specifying the format.
3. Now, you can extract the year, month or date using `df.datecolumn.dt` followed by the desired filed (e.g. `df.datecolumn.dt.year` for year, `df.datecolumn.dt.month` for month and so on..).

Here one example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": [20190101, 20190803, 20191231]})

# Create a date object
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.col.astype(str), format="%Y%m%d")
print(df)
#         col       date
# 0  20190101 2019-01-01
# 1  20190803 2019-08-03
# 2  20191231 2019-12-31

# Extract the year, month and date from the date
df["year"] = df.date.dt.year
df["month"] = df.date.dt.month
df["day"] = df.date.dt.day
print(df)
#         col       date  year  month  day
# 0  20190101 2019-01-01  2019      1    1
# 1  20190803 2019-08-03  2019      8    3
# 2  20191231 2019-12-31  2019     12   31
```